# Need to know how to select a variable, based on which button I click on (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

So, I have some images on which I can click on and they trigger a comparison function. I also have some variables defined in my program.

I need to know how I can go about making an event listener that will know which image I clicked on and select the appropriate variable for use in the comparison. I am using JavaScript as the language. Was wondering if anyone had some suggestions or knew a way to do something like this.

Some of the code:

```
 // the image button
<div> <button onclick="Tri_Peak_Game();">
<img class="card" id="leftRow4E1" src="cardback.jpg" alt="cardback"
style="width: 100px; height: 150px; top: 200px; left: 150px; position: absolute;" />
</button> </div>

// Then I would have a variable like this 
var foo;
```

Comment: That code looks amazing, do you have more?

Comment: I do have the function already written that does the comparison I need. The problem I am having is I don't know how to get the program to know which specific image I clicked on. So I can then use that knowledge to select which variable corresponds to that image and tell if the card can be played or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a parameter to the function that you are calling on `onclick`.

```
<button onclick="Tri_Peak_Game('card_1');">
  <img class="card" id="leftRow4E1" src="cardback.jpg" alt="cardback"
   style="width: 100px; height: 150px; top: 200px; left: 150px; position: absolute;" />
</button>
<button onclick="Tri_Peak_Game('card_2');">
  <img class="card" id="leftRow4E1" src="cardback.jpg" alt="cardback"
   style="width: 100px; height: 150px; top: 200px; left: 150px; position: absolute;" />
</button>
```

Or you can just simply pass `this`. This way you have access to the very element that you have clicked on.

```
<button onclick="Tri_Peak_Game(this);">
  <img class="card" id="leftRow4E1" src="cardback.jpg" alt="cardback"
   style="width: 100px; height: 150px; top: 200px; left: 150px; position: absolute;" />
</button>
```